# formatting output of replicate()

Tags: r

I am trying to find empirically the answer to a probability problem,

"what is the probability that the first die of 2 thrown is a 6, if the sum is 8".

I want a 2-column matrix or dataframe with the results of n=1000 throws of 2 die.

```
sample(1:6, 2, replace=T)
```

gives me one throw, but

```
replicate(1000,sample(1:6,2, replace=T))
```

gives me unreadable output. I have tried

```
as.matrix(replicate(1000,sample(1:6,2, replace=T)), nrow=1000, ncol=2) #and
do.call(cbind,list(rolls))
```

and neither give the two column format I am looking for

Comment: `t(replicate(1000, sample(1:6, 2, TRUE)))`

Comment: also nice; so replicate was returning a 2 x 1000 matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nThrows <- 1000
matrix(sample(1:6, nThrows * 2, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)
```

Instead or replicating 2 throws 1000 times just sample 2000 numbers and split them into two column matrix.

Comment: perfect. How come my call to as.matrix() didn't do that?